# How to get origin of namespace used inside a Tcl Proc

Tags: oop, tcl

I have the following function or a procedure decalration as shown below in which the proc name itself is a namespace coming from somewhere else, I mean a different file. How do I get to know where that namespace is coming from , means from which file ?

Example:

```
proc ::a::b {some argument} {
    body
}
```

In the eg shown above, I want to know explicitly where is the namespace "a" from ::a::b coming from or used. It's not in the same file and in the same dir there are like 100 other files.

I tried using namespace code and namespace origin but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not willing to just search across your source code (easy enough with real procedure names, but not so much when using short examples like `b`!) you can build up the information about where things are defined by detecting what `proc` does. This all works because `proc` is *just an ordinary command*.

### Overloading `proc` to add tracking

The classic way of doing this is by renaming `proc` and putting a tracking command (a procedure) in its place that delegates to the original renamed `proc` once it's done:

```
rename proc _real_proc
_real_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    global definitionLocations
    if {![string match "::*" $name]} {
        set name ::[string trimleft [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]::$name ":"]
    }
    set definitionLocations($name) [file normalize [info script]]
    uplevel 1 [list _real_proc $name $arguments $body]
}
```

If you put that code before you `source` any of your other application code, it will keep track of exactly where each procedure is defined in the global `definitionLocations` array.

### Attaching the tracking with a trace

The other way to attach this monitoring code is with an execution trace:

```
trace add execution proc enter {apply {{arguments op} {
    global definitionLocations
    set name [lindex $arguments 1]
    if {![string match "::*" $name]} {
        set name ::[string trimleft [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]::$name ":"]
    }
    set definitionLocations($name) [file normalize [info script]]
}}}
```

I'm not sure if this is neater than overriding `proc` (traces scare me a bit, to be honest) but I suppose it is a bit less intrusive…

However, the point still applies about still needing the tracking to be attached before the procedure in question is defined.

Comment: Thanks Donal Fellows, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: I am scared to use trace execution myself, but for the quick turn around time of the task in hand the overloading proc works like a charm ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably the easiest is a grep.

If you want to do it in pure Tcl, there are a few options:

1. Trace `namespace` so you know when it is called. You can get the current executed file with `info script`. <sub>Has to be done before this namespace is created</sub>
2. Replace `namespace` with your own thing, works like 1. <sub>Has to be done before the namespace is created</sub>
3. If there is a proc inside this namespace that was created in the same file as the namespace was created, you can add a `trace execution add enterstep` and use `info frame` to get the file where this proc was defined. <sub>Can be done later</sub>

Comment: Thanks Johannes, grep is a bandage solution and then I had to tee it to a log and then parse from that log.

Comment: I needed a Tcl based solution and I think trace execution is the way to go, thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Go for **The Tcl Dev Kit Cross Reference Tool (XRef**) , If you are looking for the file which the namespaces reside in.
 The XRef tool scans Tcl source code, and then builds a cross-referenced database showing you the relationships among Tcl code components. These components include packages, files, **namespaces**, commands, and variables. Each Tcl component is presented in a tree hierarchy that can be expanded to display where the code is defined, declared, used, and located.

There are some other cross-referencing tools too.

Comment: Thanks PHIfounder, but for the quick turnaround task I had, getting a Kit and running was not feasible at the time. However it is a good idea though.